# appending on ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

I am trying to append new text to an existing column if it fits within the parameters.

Here is the dataset I am working on:

```
      Kod     PC1_05 Rank_05     PC1_18 Rank_18      PC_Chg Rank_Chg Zcore_rank_change Status
1 1010110 -1.6952721      21 -1.7914811      10 -0.09620898      -11        -0.2724456 Stable
2 1010120 -1.3518838      67 -1.4729535      59 -0.12106977       -8        -0.1981423 Stable
3 1010130 -0.7793791     138 -0.9511099     114 -0.17173080      -24        -0.5944268 Stable
4 1010140 -0.2219527     192 -0.6900887     145 -0.46813601      -47        -1.1640857 Stable
5 1010201 -1.4540743      55 -1.6195653      41 -0.16549094      -14        -0.3467489 Stable
6 1010210 -1.4193512      57 -1.5769924      43 -0.15764116      -14        -0.3467489 Stable
```

and trying to filter out the ones above the 70th percentile and append 'accending' to the `Status` column.

I tried this below but it seems to change all of the `status` columns to 'accending' and not just those above the 70th percentile.

```
composite_index_merge <- composite_index_merge %>%
  mutate(Status =  ifelse(PC_Chg > quantile(PC_Chg , c(.70)), Status  <-   'Accending', Status))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly assign the values using :

```
df$Status[df$PC_Chg > quantile(df$PC_Chg, 0.7)] <- 'Accending'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
composite_index_merge <- composite_index_merge %>%
  mutate(Status =  ifelse(PC_Chg > quantile(PC_Chg , c(.70)),'Accending', Status))
```

You don't need to define `Status <-` when the `mutate(Status =`  already takes care of that.

Comment: Ah, understood! Thanks!